# Call Electron method from Frontend

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I'm trying to figure out how to call an Electron method from my frontend application javascript.  Either the main or renderer process would do fine for starters, presumably I can work through the rest from there.

In all the examples I can find, the renderer code attaches to the frontend element and adds an event listener:

```
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener(() => { // doElectronStuff });
```

This is not quite what I'm after though... it seems like a rather severe coupling to have this "server side" code reaching into my DOM.

Using an Angular2 frontend, I found what appears to be a nice package called [ngx-electron](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron%20ngx-electron) which exposes the electron interface as an injectable complete with typescript mappings, etc.

So now I have an Angular service that I want to call an Electron method for (to grab some database stuff, or whatever else):

```
constructor(private _electron:ElectronService) {}

getAll(): Entity[] {
    var results = this._electron.ipcRenderer.?????
}
```

I really have no idea how to make the angular service make that call to the electron method.  I've tried running `emit()` and have tried using `send()` and such against the `ipcRenderer`, the `remote.ipcMain`, but receive various errors and all and all can't seem to make the connection.

Hopefully I missing something simple?  What's the combination of electron-side syntax and angular-side syntax that's required to match these up?  Thanks

(I'm not particularly stuck on ngx-electron, but it did seem a nice lib and I'm assuming it works well, once I get past my own block...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.  As usual, an oversight on my end.

```
// in the angular service
this._electron.ipcRenderer.send('event-aka-channel-name1', args);

// in the electron main.js
ipc.on('event-aka-channel-name1', (event, args) => { // doStuff });
```

My issue was apparently a misspelling of an import which I caught via various logs.  Once that was fixed the rest works as intended (or at least enough for me to move forward)

Comment: I know this is kind of old, but can you maybe share a working example please?. When I try the client side ipcRenderer is null.